# Multiple VB6 apartments in C# application

Tags: c#, com, vb6, appdomain, sta

We have very old legacy **vb6** application, that has one global object that serves as Application Core, that stores different application settings, invokes database operations and so on. Multiple modules with different progid use this global object and have no problem with it due to single-thread apartment.

Not long ago new WPF application was created, that provide us transition from vb6, however it is still limited by vb6 legacy due to some architectural mistakes. It is able to connect to only one database per app instance. It hold static instance of vb6 global object in wrapper class, that serves as bridge to reach legacy functionality.

Now, we are developing new application that should not be limited by old legacy code, in particular it new application should be able to connect to several databases at once, but there is a catch: vb6 code limited to single database, so there should be several instances of  vb6 global objects, one per each database.

So the question is: is it possible, and if it is, how is it possible to use several separated intstances of global vb6 objects in same C# application?

I presume that each instance of such object should live in it's own **STA**-Thread, but i don't know how to create such threads, that are kept alive for entire application runtime and that have assotiated wrappers, containing instances of global vb6 objects and supporting invocation of some functions from GUI thread (and how to organize such cross-thread communication, there is no thread.invoke(...)). I thinked about using wpf dispatcherization model ( wrapper class is DispatcherObject, each instance has it's own Dispatcher with it's own STA-Thread), but i cannot see how to implement such thing. Also I think it could be imlemented by loading each instance of wrapper class (static) in different AppDomains, but i don't know if it resolves STA problem for COM.

Comment: An interesting question.  Are you sure it wouldn't be less trouble (and more reliable, easier to maintain, etc) to just recode the vb6 global object in c#?

Comment: We cannot just recode vb6 global code because we will have to recode every vb6 module that use it - and it's a lot of work (and nobody even wants to touch it, it would much easier to rewrite these modules in C# from scratch. But it's also will take a long time, so we are trying to achieve bacward compatibility with old modules in new application)

Comment: This is a built-in capability of VB6.  If you configured it correctly then creating the Application object again should start *another* instance of the out-of-process server.  Completely isolated from the first, it can talk to its own database.

Comment: You can recode the VB6 global object, but only use the new version in new, .NET code. The existing code would continue to use the old VB6 object.

Comment: Note also that the VB6 global object may not work properly in multiple threads. There has only been a single thread for how many decades, and now you want to change the assumption that there is only one thread. Doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @Hans Passant, yes, it works for out-of-process server (but with limitations, i presume, my coworker said that he had succeeded affecting working one process, launched as standalone exe, to be affected by same exe, launched under visual studio 6 debugger). But this global vb6 object is in fact in-process server, stored in dll, which is referenced by old app exe (an thus stored in STA of that exe's thread) and by wrapper class project in new app

Comment: Hmm, "Application" is rather a poor choice for a name.  Hosting them in separate .NET processes is technically possible.  This does turn into Monty Python's Flying Circus in a hurry though.

Comment: @John Saunders, And that is the reason to isolate different global objects in it's own threads. If two global objects are stored in a same thread, than every loaded vb module (dll registered in system by regsvr32 and loaded by Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(progid)) sees only latter global object

Comment: Threads aren't the only issue. Threads are not independent from each other. Code running on two different threads may still use common memory, if the code was written to assume there is only one thread.

Comment: @HansPassant Actual name is much more horrid: Kernel\tickApplic.cAppGlobal... this code is not old - it is ancient :(. Anyway, if it is technically possible, could you direct me to some specifics about possible implementation?

Comment: You might get away with running one instance of the global object per AppDomain. To be safe, you should run them each in their own process, since that's the assumption they were created with. I guarantee you that horrible things can happen when you violate the assumptions of ancient code - especially when you introduce them to things which simply did not exist when they were written.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I see. Please post that as an answer so I can accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get away with running one instance of the global object per `AppDomain`.

To be safe, you should run them each in its own process, since that's the assumption they were created with. I guarantee you that horrible things can happen when you violate the assumptions of ancient code - especially when you introduce them to things which simply did not exist when they were written.

Comment: VB6 uses TLS for global state. The only way to share state across threads is through COM marshalled function calls. So it is actually very safe to use a singleton object per thread -- no assumptions are broken in this case. The only trouble are STA threads tear-downs because the runtime is leaking and this was not fixed. And then MS abandoned the whole language.

Comment: This will not work. VB6, COM, has no notion of .NET AppDomains. If VB6 state is global to the loaded process, it continues to be, nomatter how many AppDomains your .NET code is in.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, using what is referred to as unmanaged code. Check out this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154144/Using-Unmanaged-VB6-Code-in-NET